# how to specify either or placeholder

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that takes phone number as input in a field
I have set the type as tel as per HTML5 standard. I need the input to accept either 8 digit or 10 digit values.

I tried

```
<input type='tel' placeholder='0123456789 or 12345678'></input>
```

i also tried adding  `pattern="[0-9]{8} or [0-9]{10}` 
but, did not work,
 is there an other way

Comment: What didn't it do that you're expecting it to do?

Comment: I need the input to accept either 8 digit or 10 digit values.

Comment: I need the input to accept either 8 digit or 10 digit values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the pattern I would recommend for telephone numbers but this should do as you ask:

<strike>pattern='[0-9]{8,10}'</strike>

```
<input type='tel' pattern='[0-9]{8}([0-9]{2})?' title='Phone Number (8 or 10 numbers)' />
```

Comment: oops, my bad. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I advise you currently do not use "tel" as the input type. The reason for this is that it is not yet supported by all the major browser providers. It might be suitable for say Google Chrome, but other browsers such as IE aren't able to support this input type yet. I personally stick to keeping the type as text for input on telephone numbers.

Secondly, the way you can limit the persons input amount is using the maxlength attribute.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10"/>
```

Finally, the input tag is self closing. It's used in the format below:

```
<input />
```

Not:

```
<input></input>
```

Hope this helped. For more, look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: What do I do to accept minimum 8 digit and not to accept 9 digit values

Comment: Try maxlength="8" minlength="8" inside your input tag                                    DISREGARD THIS: Stupid answer from myself lol. Use php or javascript to validate it

Comment: The best way to validate your input is either using javascript or php to do it. You'll be able to do a series of if statements to check the length of the input

Comment: FYI It's perfectly fine to use `input type='tel'` as any unsupported type will revert to `type=text`

Comment: That is true but when you're hooking your site up to a database of some sort it's easier to just use the text type. That way you wont have some data coming through as int and some as string. At least, I'm pretty sure tel sends data through as integer

Answer (score 0):

Change your input tag to this;

```
<input type="text" min="8" max="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself guys

it was to be done with pattern attribute itself

```
<input type='tel' placeholder='0123456789' pattern='[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{10}'>
```

here **'|'** is the or in expression, thank guys however.

```
pattern='[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{10}'
```

resolved my problem